# Insert HTML content into template with Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have a set of files (HTML fragments) that I'm serving up with Node.js as follows:

```
var finalhandler = require('finalhandler')
var http = require('http')
var serveIndex = require('serve-index')
var serveStatic = require('serve-static')

// Serve directory indexes for all files in the folder
var index = serveIndex('./', {'icons': true})

// Serve up public/ftp folder files
var serve = serveStatic('./')

// Create server
var server = http.createServer(function onRequest(req, res){
  var done = finalhandler(req, res)
  serve(req, res, function onNext(err) {
    console.log(req,res)
    if (err) return done(err)
    index(req, res, done)
  })
})

// Listen
server.listen(3000)
```

This serves up an index with a list of active links to the HTML files.  I need the linked HTML files to be contained in a template (i.e., put the same header on each page, and read in the same css files). When I use the `template` option as described in the [documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-index#template), the only content that is served up is the template:

```
// Serve directory indexes for public/ftp folder (with icons)
var index = serveIndex('./', {'icons': true, template:'template.html'})
```

How do I use a template or other configuration to serve up the HTML fragments inside the default HTML?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add something to your template to actually display the files like this:

```
<body class="directory">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <h1><a href="/">~</a>{linked-path}</h1>
    {files}
  </div>
</body>
```

If you take a look at the serve-index installation directory under /public you will find the default template file called directory.html. You can cut and paste some of that code to get your files to display.